# joint histogram without using inbuilt functions

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing, histogram

So, I'm writing a function to create a 2d joint histogram of two images in Python.
This is the code I have written to produce the histogram.

```
    import numpy as np

    Img1=imread(img1.jpg)
    Img2=imread(img2.jpg)    
    hist_2d, x_edges, y_edges = np.histogram2d(Img1.ravel(),Img2.ravel(),bins=bins)
    
    plt.imshow(hist_2d.T,origin='lower')
```

How can write this function without using any inbuilt functions except the basic numpy functions? (but not direct histogram functions).
Basically what can I put in place on 'histogram2d' to get the same output?

Comment: @AcaNg I'm not sure what you mean. Could you provide an example illustration?

Comment: NumPy is open source. You can go in an look at how the function is implemented. That’s a much better way of learning than hoping the answer you get here is correct.

Comment: sorry i misread your question. please forget what i've commented. from [the doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html), basically you can get `(x_edges, y_edges)` from `bins`. from [`np.histogram`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) (if that method is allowed) you can get [marginal histograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) of the 2 images. You'll have to find out how `histogram2d` creates joint histogram from these, as [there are many ways to do it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77334/).